¿Cómo puedo comparar la asistencia si la fecha actual esta registrada en la tabla y/o la columna de la hora de salida es nula?
Me encuentro desarrollando un programa de sistema de asistencia para alumnos de mi universidad como proyecto de residencias profesionales en Java. Ya tengo todo terminado, solo me falta completar la parte de registrar la asistencia, pero me encuentro algo estresado por tratar de tener el resultado satisfactorio. Intenté muchas veces en sobrescribir el método que permite comparar la fecha actual y si la columna de la hora de salida esta en nulo, debe de marcarme como verdadero y me habilita el botón de salida, mientras que el botón de entrada la deshabilita por que el programa ya detectó que tiene la hora de entrada registrada en la tabla.
He visto algunos programas de registro de asistencia que siempre usan un combobox que permite marcar y registrar la hora de entrada y salida. Como este ejemplo:

En mi caso, decidí mejor usar botones y el sensor de la huella digital para darle un toque más único y que no sea repetitivo, el programa debe de detectar cuando se crea un nuevo registro de asistencia y que no registre una fecha anterior para realizar la hora de entrada.
public boolean CompararAsistencia(String id){
    id = lblD3.getText();
    String fecha = lblFecha.getText();
    String salida = null;
    boolean res = false;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String query = "SELECT asis.idAsistencia, asis.fecha, asis.hrEntrada, asis.hrSalida FROM asistencia AS asis JOIN alumno AS alm WHERE alm.idAlumno = asis.idAlumno AND asis.idAlumno = '"+id+"'";
    try{
        Statement stmt = Conexion.conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while(rs.next()){
            fecha = rs.getString("fecha");
            salida = rs.getString("hrSalida");
            if(fechaActual() != fecha || salida == null){
                res = false;
            }
            else{
                if(fechaActual() == fecha && salida == null){
                    res = true;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrió un problema con la conexión, favor de verificar si"
            + "\n" + "la base de datos se encuentre activa y conectada con el programa.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}

Ya tengo la hora registrada en la tabla del registro #4.

Sin embargo, cuando trato de entrar a la ventana de Tomar Asistencia, la bandera no me marca como verdadero y no se ejecuta el método de habilitar el botón de salida para registrar la hora de fin de jornada de actividades, como tampoco desactiva el botón de entrada cuando ya tiene la hora registrada en la tabla.

Les muestro el código donde permite habilitar el botón de salida.
public FrmRegAsistencia(String userAl){
    this();
    FrmRegAsistencia.userAl = userAl;
    CargarDatos(userAl);
    Iniciar();
    start();
    
    String id = lblD3.getText();
    if(CompararAsistencia(id)){
        btnEntrada.setEnabled(false);
        btnSalida.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

Agradecería si alguien me ayude con este problema que tengo, ya que necesito tenerlo listo para la revisión de evaluación final de Residencias Profesionales.

Hola Alan, bienvenido,  si no estoy muy dormido, diría que dado que tienes: if(CompararAsistencia(id)){
btnEntrada.setEnabled( false );
btnSalida.setEnabled( true );
} deberías tener también: else {
btnEntrada.setEnabled( true );
btnSalida.setEnabled( false );
}, para que habilite el otro botón.

Hola @MarcePuente, voy a intentar a poner el else para comprobarlo.

Hola de nuevo @MarcePuente, pues, si intenté lo de poner el else de los botones, sin embargo, en el método de comparar asistencia sigue sin funcionar como quería, porque, cuando quiero registrar la hora de salida, me arroja que el booleano es false sin importar que haya comparado la fecha actual con la que se registró en la tabla.

Te referís a que CompararAsistencia devuelve siempre false?, si es así, la única forma de que devuela true es si fechaActual es igual a fecha y salida es ull, por lo que jamas va adevolver true, ya que el primer if es: fechaActual() != fecha || salida == null. siendo salida "null", siempre entra ahí.

¿Cómo esta definida la columna de hora de salida en la BDD?

@MarcePuente, si, es lo que me refiero de que el método de CompararAsistencia devuelve false, de hecho, tuve que sobrescribir el código de ese método: 'if(fecha == fechaActual()){
res = true;
}
else{
res = false;
}'

@Sal, la tengo definida como nulo, ya que primero se requiere que se registre la hora de entrada cuando un alumno empieza a realizar sus actividades de su servicio como servicio social.

Me refiero al tipo de dato, ¿manejas horas como cadena? ¿la cadena podría ser vacía?.

@Sal, pues, no se que decirte sobre eso, pero supongo que si manejo como cadena, aunque de todos modos ya alguien me dio la respuesta que necesitaba que resolver el código, aún así, muchas gracias por el apoyo.

Primero, decir que tu código podría ser vulnerable a la inyección SQL. Para no hacerlo muy complejo, no resolveré ese punto en mi respuesta, pero es algo que tienes que revisar.
Hay varios errores en tu código, pero el error más importante, a mi manera de ver, es de la manera de enfocar el problema.
Sugiero partir de una idea un poco más simple, que nace desde la manera en la que expresamos el problema en lenguaje coloquial.
Entiendo que quieres que tu sistema sea más inteligente, habilitando solo el botón de entrada o el de salida, según sea el caso.
En realidad, lo que necesitamos saber para lograr este cometido, es si hay un registro del alumno que tiene no tenga hora de salida. Si todos tienen hora de salida, podemos asumir que se trata de una nueva entrada, por lo que habría que crear un registro nuevo.
Si hay uno que no tiene salida, entonces asumimos lo contrario. Es decir, que se trata de la salida para ese registro.
Para esto, podemos definir un método que nos dé la respuesta, por ejemplo, basarla en realizar la cuenta de cuántos registros en la tabla tienen el campo hrSalida en null. Si hay más de cero, entonces, hay salida pendiente:
public boolean estudianteTieneRegistroSinSalida(String id) {
    boolean res = false;
    String query = "SELECT count(1) contador FROM asistencia AS asis WHERE  asis.idAlumno = '"+id+"' and asis.hrSalida is null";
    try{
        Statement stmt = Conexion.conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        rs.next();
        res = rs.getInteger("contador") > 0;
    } catch(SQLException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrió un problema con la conexión, favor de verificar si"
            + "\n" + "la base de datos se encuentre activa y conectada con el programa.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}

La habilitación de los botones podría lucir algo así:
bool tieneSalidaPendiente = estudianteTieneRegistroSinSalida(id);
btnEntrada.setEnabled(!tieneSalidaPendiente);
btnSalida.setEnabled(tieneSalidaPendiente);

Ya con esto en mente, pueden venir algunas mejoras. Por ejemplo, puedes querer que la validación se haga solo sobre el último registro del estudiante en la tabla, y no sobre todos los registros.
Para ello, haría falta saber la información solo del último registro, podrías cambiar el query que hace la cuenta y la lógica para responder. Una consulta que te diga si el último registro tiene hora de salida podría ser algo como:
select top 1 hrSalida
  from asistencia
 where idAlumno = '1'
 order by idAsistencia

Ahora, la rutina solo tendría que evaluar si el campo hrSalida es NULL o no, para poder responder. También puedes realizar la evaluación en SQL y devolver 1 o 0, para no cambiar la lógica anterior, solo que ahora aplicada sobre el campo bandera y ya no contador
select top 1 case when hrSalida is null then 1 else 0 end bandera
  from asistencia
 where idAlumno = '1'
 order by idAsistencia

Finalmente, si el lugar donde usan el sistema no está abierto a la media noche, otra mejora podría ser validar solo en registros del día de hoy, por ejemplo valiéndote de la función curdate():
select top 1 case when hrSalida is null then 1 else 0 end bandera
  from asistencia
 where idAlumno = '1'
   and fecha = curdate()
 order by idAsistencia


Intenté probar su solución en el programa, y de verdad, si me funcionó con totalidad, ahora ya se puede registrar la hora de entrada y salida sin complicaciones, como también que cada botón funcione cuando el programa detecte si hay horas registradas o no. Muchas gracias por su ayuda, se lo agradezco.

Si no estoy entendiendo mal lo que comentas, tu bolque if/else está mal.
Decis: "comparar la fecha actual y si la columna de la hora de salida esta en nulo, debe de marcarme como verdadero y me habilita el botón de salida, mientras que el botón de entrada la deshabilita por que el programa ya detectó que tiene la hora de entrada registrada en la tabla".
Entonces deberías tener algo como esto:
fecha = rs.getString( "fecha" );
salida = rs.getString( "hrSalida" );
if( fechaActual() != fecha ) {
    // del comportamiento esperado en esta condición, no estoy seguro...
    btnEntrada.setEnabled( false );
    btnSalida.setEnabled( false );
}
else{
   if( entrada == null ) {
      btnEntrada.setEnabled( true );
      btnSalida.setEnabled( false );
   }
   else if( salida == null ) {
      btnEntrada.setEnabled( false );
      btnSalida.setEnabled( true );
   }
}

Espero haberte ayudado, sino, seguimos intentando en los comentarios.
